# Pipe isn't returning the right values

Tags: angular

I have a pipe that is supposed to add the sub totals together to return the grand total but it just returns the sub total. It returns sub_total = product_price * quantity; and not the sum of the sub totals.

This is my pipe:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'grandtotal'
})
export class GrandTotalPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(product_price: number, 
              quantity: number,
              sub_total: number,
              grand_total: number,
              totals: any[]) { 

        var totals = [];
        sub_total = product_price * quantity;
        totals.push(sub_total);
        var i;
        var grand_total = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < totals.length; i++) {
            grand_total += totals[i];
        }
        return grand_total;
   }
}
```

This is how I call the pipe in the HTML:

```
<div>Grand Total {{ product_price | grandtotal:  quantity : sub_total : grand_total : totals  }}</div>
```

I tried making a getter like the following but it produces a blank page:

```
get grandTotal() {
var i;
var sub_total;
var grand_total;
sub_total = this.product_price * this.quantity;
this.totals.push(sub_total);
for (i = 0; i < this.totals.length; i++) {
 grand_total += this.totals[i];
}
return grand_total;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that this is the correct way to use a pipe. You are passing in `grand_total` and `totals`, but also immediately overriding them in your `transform` method. You should just have a pipe which takes an array of prices and quantities

Comment: You're overwriting the `totals` array with an empty array and pushing only one value to it. So the loop is iterated only once. Also I don't understand why you'd send the temporary variables `sub_total` and `grand_total` as parameters.

Comment: When I remove "var totals = [];", I get "cannot read property push of undefined." When I just use "var totals;", I get "Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'totals' must be of type 'any[]', but here has type 'any'."

Comment: I've tried putting "var totals = [];" everywhere. I've tried putting it before the transform function and I've tried putting it in the component. It can't go anywhere except where it is now but that's leading to my issue so that's no good.

Comment: I removed sub_total, totals, and grand_total from the parameters.

Comment: I edited my question to show the getter that I tried.

Comment: I initialize totals outside of the getter function as totals: any[]; and I call the getter in the HTML with <div>Grand Total {{ grandTotal }}</div>

Comment: When I put var totals = []; into my getter it returns a value but the totals array is set to null each time so it returns the wrong value.

Comment: My getter throws the following error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: When I use totals : number[ ] = [ ]; instead of totals: any[];, the typeerror goes away but it displays NaN for the grand total.

Comment: I used 
this.product_price = parseFloat(this.product_price) || 0;
this.quantity = parseInt(this.quantity) || 0;
and the NaN went away but the value is still wrong and I get the error:
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked.

Answer (score 0):

Here, need to modify some code.

**Create a class** in typescript

```
class PriceInfo 
{
   Quantity: number;
   ItemPrice: number;
}
```

**Pipe**

```
@Pipe({name: 'grandtotal'})
export class GrandTotalPipe implements PipeTransform {
     transform(priceInfo: PriceInfo) { 
        let grand_total = priceInfo.ItemPrice * priceInfo.Quantity;
        return grand_total;
 }
```

}

Comment: That will return the sub_total priceInfo.ItemPrice * priceInfo.Quantity; and not the sum of the sub_totals which would be grandtotal.

Comment: Thanks anyways Ranjeet Kumar